# How to move c# application to Azure cloud?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, azure-function-app-proxy

I have a application written in c# supporting **Azure stream analytics**.I need to move my application to cloud. Whether "function app service" along with **deployment option of GitHub** will work? I know how to deploy the files from github to function app. But how to deploy and run the github files? Any other suggestions to move the application to cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Here you will get the continuos deployment solution for all source controls
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment